# If I need to get properties for a component from an API should I do that before the component loads?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Say I have a comp that is inside of a Scene (`react-native-router-flux`). It lets people choose their favorite fruits.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {MKCheckbox} from 'react-native-material-kit';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default class PickAFruit extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.fruits);
    return (
      <View>
        {
          this.props.fruits.map((x)=> {
            return (
              <View key={x.key}>
                <Text>{x.key}</Text>
                <MKCheckbox checked={this.props.checked} key={x.key} onCheckedChange={(e) => {
                  this.props.update(e, '' + x.key)
                }}/>
              </View>
            )
          })
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

In the parent comp I'm loading the list of fruits from an API in the didMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ApiInst.getFruits().then((fruits) => {
      console.log(fruits);
      console.log(this.props.fruits);
      this.props.fruits = fruits;         
    });

  }
```

I'm also setting a default `fruits` array in the parent class. It seems like the properties won't load via the API though, the list of fruit is always the "unknown" value, never the new values. Do I need to load the list of fruits before the Profile scene is loaded? When is the correct time to set properties for a component if they will come from an API?

`setState` seems like the easy answer but these settings don't "feel" like state, they feel like properties that would be injected at build-time (i.e. when the component is built, not the app). Is this a distinction without a real difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify props. Props are passed from parent to child component, and only the parent can change them.

Use `setState` instead:

```
this.setState({fruits: fruits});
```

And access them from state:

```
<PickAFruit fruits={this.state.fruits} />
```

You may also want to set a default state in the component constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(this);
  this.state = {fruits: null};
}
```

Comment: added a paragraph at the end about this, please update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.fruits = fruits;
```

won't effect child component, and to be honest - I'm not sure it will work at all. If you don't want to use flux architecture I think the best solution is to update parent's state on componentDidMount() and pass it as props to child component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ApiInst.getFruits().then((fruits) => {
        this.setState({fruits: fruits});         
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <PickAFruit fruits={this.state.fruits} />
    );
}
```

Every state change will invokre render() method, so after API call PickAFruit component will be rerendered, with fruits passed as a props.